# OnClick on customized ListVew (Image and Text) in android

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, customization

I am creating simple unit converter. On my main screen I want to give ListView with image and text. I don't know how to create another activity when user click any element from ListView.

Here is my code.
MainActivity.java

```
package learn2crack.customlistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
String[] web = {
            "Volume",
        "Temperature",
        "Length",
        "Bits/Bytes",
        "Mass/Weight",

} ;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+     position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });




}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a new activity from an activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent;
                if(position==0){
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class());
                } else if(position==1){
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class());
                } else if(position==2){
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class());
                } else if(position==3){
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity4.class());
                } else if(position==4){
                    intent = new Intent(this, Activity5.class());                        
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I hope this will help you. Also don't forget to add `activity` for your class in your `manifest` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below code:

```
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
               Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```